# Rotate an image with javascript in gallerio.io after load

Tags: javascript, jquery, galleria, image-rotation

I am using galleria 1.2.8. and i try to rotate an image after it is loaded by galleria. For this i am using the jquery rotate plugin (http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/). I did attach to the "loadfinish" event and then do e.imageTarget.rotate(90).
Then i get the error: "TypeError: e.imageTarget.rotate is not a function".
When i do a "e.imageTarget" in the console i do get the img object, but i suspect that its not added to the DOM already and thats why its not working.
I also tried to attach to the "image" event, but there i get the same error.

Any Ideas how i could make the rotation work with galleria?

Thanks,
Sven

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`e.imageTarget` is not a jQuery object, it's an HTML element, according to the [docs](http://galleria.io/docs/api/events/#loadfinish):

> imageTarget (HTML element) The IMG element of the now loaded image
>   before transition.

HTML elements have no property called `rotate`. You  need to wrap it in a jQuery object:

```
this.bind("loadfinish", function(e) {
    $(e.imageTarget).rotate();
});
```

Comment: Thank you, thats the solution :-)